# The input is correct, but the output does not match the input

Tags: java, input, output, match

I´m making a simple a+b calculator as one of my first projects in Java. 
And I know that the Result should be 12. Java even shows me that the result is 12, but if I type in that the result is 12, my code tells me that the input doesn´t equal the result.

I´ve been sitting over this for a while now and I do not understand what I´m doing wrong.

Could somebody please help me?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodMan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculate(5, 7);
    }
    public static void calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("What is: " + a + "+" + b + "?");
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        int result = a + b;

        if (input.equals(result)) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong: The Result is: "+result);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Your input is a string and needs to be converted to int using Integer.valueOf(input)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Input to an int. Use Integer.parseInt(), but you have to put that into a try catch statement, as it is possible that the String isnt convertable (if you dont type in a whole number).And as int is a primitive datatype you dont need equals, == is enough.

You could also convert the result into a String and use the equals method.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (input.equals(result)) {
```

to

```
if (Integer.parseInt(input) == result) {
```